# Twitter authentication without using web page or safari?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've seen some iOS libraries for authenticating Twitter on iOS, and they all present Twitter's own authentication web page in a UIWebView.

However, I've also seen a few iPhone apps on the store which just present the user with a couple of UITextFields to enter, which seems more professional. How have they done this, and is there any example code which does this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply for xAuth use you can do this by going to [Twitter's xAuth page,](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) where you can then apply for your app to have xAuth and then for the actual code check out this: [st3fan /iPhone-twitter using xAuth.](https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a Twitter engine,
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

This is very easy to use, and can be adopted seamlessly with your current codes.
I use this extensively, and it has native xAuth support.

Answer (score 0):

An overview and explanation of twitters current authorization methods can be found here:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth_overview

From your description I think you are talking about oauth echo or xauth.